# How calculate list python into matrix similarity

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I got problem with my data

I have data read from my DB use python, let's say assign to variable `data`

`type(data)` is `list`, actually `list of list`

```
data = [(1, 'Shirt', 2),(1, 'Pants', 3),(2, 'Top', 2),(2, 'Shirt', 1),(2, 'T-Shirt', 4), (3, 'Shirt', 3),(3, 'T-Shirt', 2)]
```

`data[0][0] is unique_id` and `data[0][1] is category_product` and `data[0][2] is count`

i need to calculate similarity between `unique_id` 1 and 2 using cosine similarity (i plan use `scipy`) based on `category_product`

- `unique_id` not just two, it can be more than 2

I think i need to transform my `data` into matrix :

```
unique_id | Shirt | Pants | Top | T-Shirt
1 | 2 | 3 | 0 | 0 
2 | 1 | 0 | 2 | 4
3 | 3 | 0 | 0 | 2
```

and i want calculate this matrix using cosine similarity, and output is :

```
1,2,0.121045506534
1,3,0.461538461538
2,3,0.665750285936
```

- `Sim(1,2) = 0.121045506534`

how can i do that with python ?

thx

Comment: Your data is not a list of lists, it's a list of tuples :) There is a profound difference.

Comment: ah yeay you right, sorry my mistake :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd
from scipy import spatial
from itertools import combinations

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['unique_id', 'category_product', 'count'])

pt = df.pivot(index='unique_id', columns='category_product', values='count').fillna(0)

>>> pt
category_product  Pants  Shirt  T-Shirt  Top
unique_id                                   
1                     3      2        0    0
2                     0      1        4    2
3                     0      3        2    0

combos = combinations(pt.index, 2)
>>> [(a, b, 1 - spatial.distance.cosine(pt.ix[a].values, pt.ix[b].values)) 
     for a, b in combos]
[(1, 2, 0.12104550653376045),
 (1, 3, 0.46153846153846168),
 (2, 3, 0.66575028593568275)]
```

Comment: maybe it's need `import pandas as pd` right ?

thx @alexander

Comment: Hi @Alexander, sorry, if my real data and assign to `pt` it's become `[4260 rows x 248 columns]`, how make it faster calculate ? thx :)

Comment: With 4260 unique ID values, there are roughly (4260^2) / 2 possible pairings.  The only way to speed it up is get a faster computer or reduce the number of unique IDs.  There are other solutions, but they are pretty specialized and beyond this forum.